# Operating matrix sequences

Tags: matlab, matrix, sequence

I'm working with a really large number of matrix, just different in a single number (meanT0601, meanT0602,meanT0603,... and so on).
I know how to process a sequence of files by using a **for** loop and **%d**
but I'm unable to do something similar with matrices.
Any idea about that?? Although it will be a great lost of time I'm considering type every different matrix name to process them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use lots of matrices with different names, but to combine them into a 3D array or cell array.

Comment: Btw, to create now a 3D array I need to use a for loop, don't I?

Comment: Where are your matrices coming from?

Comment: The matrices were generated previously from .grb files (589x31 each matrix). Now I wold like to create a 589x31x72 array

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the command importdata (maybe my matlab version is too old), but if I'm using a combination of dlmread and dlmwrite it works fine.

```
 A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
 dlmwrite('file.txt',A);
 B{1} = dlmread('file.txt');
```

Dlmread and dkmwrite save in a csv format. In the End everything is in the cell array B. If you have to use the importdata function, please provide the source or documentation